# Pin a version number of git revision with pip install --target

Tags: python, git, pip, dependencies

I have two Python projects in separate repos, say: `common` and `depends_on_common`.

Due to the constraints of our deployment environment (I do not have ssh access), I'm hoping to use

```
pip install --no-deps --target common /path/to/common
```

as part of a CI/CD build stage to vendor `common` in `depends_on_common`. What I'd like to do is to specify an explicit version of common, or a git revision instead of effectively always building off of snapshot.

There is no mention of this capability in the docs:

```
-t, --target <dir>
  Install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>. Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
```

but I was hoping there was some clever way to enable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this section of the `pip install` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git) can put you in the right direction.

You probably want something like this:

```
pip install --no-deps --target ./common git+file:///path/to/common@da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#egg=common
```